# PHP $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]

Tags: php, post, compression

How can I turn `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]` into a variable to be used in a move_uploaded_file?

This works:

```
  $filename = compress_image(($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]), $url, 30);
```

But I am trying to get something like this:

```
  $filename = compress_image($images, $url, 30);
```

But, when do above it does not work.

One alternative I was starting on was:

```
  file_put_contents($target_file , $image);
```

In that case, the image was named into directory properly, but the image was always broken.

To clarify:

Need to turn ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]) into a variable that is result of

```
    ob_start(); echo imagejpeg($image,null,30); 
    $image =ob_get_clean(); 
    ob_end_clean();
     $image = addslashes($image);
```

I need to use $image to save to directory. $image has been successfully stored into mysql. I have tried encode, and decode on $image, still no luck.

Comment: Can you show a more complete code snippet ? Do you want to move uploaded file first , then compress , or compress first ? and what is the content of `compress_image()` ?

Comment: I would like to compress first. But, that task has been accomplished. Compression is not the issue.

Comment: Actually u can edit your question to update codes. Hard to read codes in comment.

Comment: and what is the value of `$image` ?

Comment: edited, and image is a rotated image, per case.

Comment: so basically need to take $image, which is rotated, and put the variable inside a move_uploaded_file or   file_put_contents. With the former I am getting nothing, with the latter (  file_put_contents) I am getting the file size and name stored on directory, but broken image.

Comment: The flow should be revised. You should move the uploaded file using `move_uploaded_file()` first, then modify the moved file.

Comment: how would I call up the file to modify for rotation? I will just compress on first upload.

Comment: If you use the `move_uploaded_file()` , you should have the absolute file path for your further processing

Comment: I am able to save $image  (rotated and compressed) in db, how do I simply use $image for a move_uploaded_file or file_put_contents

Comment: move_uploaded_file will not take successfully anything other than ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"])

Comment: Please show your `move_uploaded_file()` codes & read the manual carefully

Comment: I have made edits to include the move_uploaded_file, and believe I have looked over the manual well.

Comment: The file actually posts images to directory compressed but not rotated, and also saves to mysql db properly rotated and compressed. I need the compressed and rotated saved to directory though. That is why I was trying to take $image to move_uploaded_file

Comment: $filename = compress_image(($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]),    $url, 30); serves as the moving action in the full code above

Comment: any thoughts Raptor?

Comment: read the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the problem step-by-step:

The mess starts at this line:

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']));
```

Problems:

- Never use temp file to process; move the uploaded file to a permanent place by `move_uploaded_file()` first
- Use of `file_get_contents()` is unnecessary; you can use `imagecreatefromjpeg()` (and other formats, like GIF, PNG, etc) to replace the `imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents())` things

---

Here is your `compress_image()` function:

```
function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {
    $info = getimagesize($source_url);
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')  {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);
    }
    imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
    return $destination_url;
}
```

Problems:

- If MIME is none of the above, the `imagejpeg()` will fail (but you didn't cater it; always check the return value of function)
- you didn't check `$destination_url` is writable & exist or not

---

Next, assumes the `compress_image()` works well and returns `$destination_url` with a valid JPEG created at the path, the following codes cause further problems:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO fffdf (`user_id`,`imit`) VALUES ('9','$image')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Problems:

- Why do you save the `$image` directly into DB? It's a very bad practice to store image data in DB. Save the path instead whenever possible
- `$image` is inaccessible here; the scope of the `$image` stays in the function `compress_image()`, thus `$image` still contains the value before `compress_image()`, unless you use `global $image;` in the compress function (which is not suggested). Pass the `$image` as function parameters by reference:

  function compress_image(&$image, $destination_url, $quality)

you don't really need the `$source_url` if you have the image data stored in `$image`.

Hope the above helps.

Comment: function compress_image(&$image, $destination_url, $quality) will make $image global? If not how would $image be made global?

Comment: It is imperative that $image is posted into directory.

Comment: `&$image` will pass the variable by reference. note the `&` sign. Read more at: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php